# Problem on my binary tree class' nodes

Tags: c++, class, pointers, tree

I'm trying to code a class for binary tree representation. Each node has a value (`key`), an `index`, and a `Node*` pointer for parent(`p`), left-child(`left`) and right-child(`right`).
The problem is on pointers. It's easier giving my example problem than explaining.

I coded a `print()` function that prints out each node in the tree. [Here](http://pastebin.com/sjgJSP5B) is the class header file. And [here](http://pastebin.com/WziFCnge) is the main test file.

The problem is, when i call `T.print()`, it prints only 10, 5 and 7.

Comment: have you run the debugger already?

Comment: lines 62 and 68 should have n-2 instead of n-1.

Comment: Uhm... no, they shouldn't. It go in a forever loop if i do this. n is actually the number of nodes. They are stored in a vector, so, if the node 3 is stored, i can access through T[n-1] = 2.

Comment: why do you obviously ignore comments?

Comment: have you tested the return values of your insert calls to make sure they're returning `true`?

Comment: I don't know very well how to use gdb, but I check things through inserting cout.

Comment: Inserting the last element returns true.

Comment: @user824476: If you address other users using "@" with the _correct_ name behind it, that user will be notified. Otherwise, the chance is low he sees your reply.

Comment: @user824476: Also, you should learn to debug first. In the meanwhile, several good IDEs that have often-good-enough frontends to GDB are there: QtCreator, code::blocks, Anjuta. If all else fails, you could go the way of `std::cout`esque debugging at least, and then find the problematic code by some divide-and-conquer approach/binary-search

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/), which internally (re-)allocates storage as needed.

So, when pushing back into a vector, it could very well be that the whole internal data is copied to some other memory location - making all pointers that still point to the old locations invalid.

An easy "fix" would be to [reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/reserve/) a certain amount of space for the vector, so you can at least store a certain amount of nodes in it without re-allocation.

For example by adding this at the start of your `RootedTree` constructors :

```
T.reserve(64);
```

Note that that is not a robust solution (if you try to put more than 64 nodes in the vector, you're still likely to have the same problem) - but it'll confirm the above analysis.

Comment: @user824476 : I do not recommend the reserve approach though - for the reasons stated at the end of the answer. You might be better off storing the nodes explicitly as a tree - without using a vector for storage.

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide what kind of structure you want to represent your binary tree.

Either of

- a vector
- pointers

Not both!

So your options are

1. Removing all pointer related stuff and stick with the vector, treat the `Node` at index i as the parent to the `Nodes` at `i*2`, `i*2 + 1`. and the opposite for the child -> parent relationship.
2. Stop using the vector. Have a root node `Node * root` inside your `RootedTree` class.

They two approaches have different strengths and weaknesses, in particular, the array case lets you get rid of all the pointers, in the pointer case you don't have to worry about the performance of reallocations, and trickier manipulations like deletion is a lot easier.